# URL is missing when using dash in rails, how to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails4. I want to use dash(-) in my url, like /specials-race. I used the code like

```
root 'static_pages#index'  
match '/', to: 'static_pages#index', via: 'get'
match '/services', to: 'static_pages#services', via: 'get'
match '/schedule', to: 'static_pages#schedule', via: 'get'
match '/specials-race', to: 'static_pages#specials_race', via: 'get'
```

But the problem is when I use this my ulr disappear. How can I get back my url when using dash? I am attaching am image of routing error.

[image]
You can see the url of  /specials-race is missing.

Comment: I can see that the `/special-race` route is present.

Comment: see on the left hand side no url. service_path, schedule_path are there, but no url for /specials-race.

Comment: just a correction here @PriyankDey, the left hand side shows the route name not the urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 get 'specials-race', to: 'static_pages#specials_race', as: :my_schedule_race
```

This should add `my_schedule_race_path` helper.

Comment: ya absolutely fine. Just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Also I can use like

```
match '/specials-race', to: 'static_pages#specials_race', via: 'get', as: :schedule_race
```